# How can I detect and print what characters str_replace() changed?

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm using this code to replace words with each other.

In my scenario, in same time...Just There is one same word in #old and $string
for example `$string = "DA"` and `$string = "FJB"` is true but `$string = "BA"` or `$string = "DAHJC"` is false.

```
$string = "sdfsdfsdfA"
$old = array("A", "B", "C");
$new   = array("1", "2", "3");
$string = str_replace($old, $new, $string);
```

How can I detect which characters got replaced by `str_replace()` and print it like this:

```
Result: 'A' replaced with '1'
```

Comment: First element from old with first element from new will be replaced and so on, that easy.

Comment: ... I know how it works....I wana know after running function

Comment: Then what is the question?

Comment: for example The function say that I replace 'A' with '1'!

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: It's not important before or after function action...I just wana know what is that word.... for example I want It gives 'A' or '1' or both ,I prefer '1'.

Comment: 1. So in the example above this would be your expected output? 2. Please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29875300/edit) your attempt into your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$oldString = "sdfsdfsdfA";
$main_array=array("A"=>"1","B"=>"2", "C"=>"3");
$old=array_keys($main_array);
$new=array_values($main_array);

$newString = str_replace($old, $new, $oldString);
foreach ($main_array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($oldString,$key) !== false) {
    echo "Result: {$key} replaced with {$value} <br>";
    }
}
echo '<b>'.$oldString.'</b><br>';
echo $newString;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($old);$i++){
    echo $old[$i]." replaced by ".$new[$i]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Dont *just* post code, explain what you did there and why that is working and so on.